# Debugging "unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with URL ... "

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, iframe, browser-security

So, the error message is the security restriction to access a parent frame or window from within an (i)frame from a different domain.

(Unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with URL xxx from frame with URL yyy. Domains, protocols, and ports must match).

However, there is no line shown in webkit or chrome from where this error is generated.

So how do I get a list of the lines that infringe upon this? I know I can just search, but does this apply to cookies as well (document.cookie, etc) ? Is there a list of things that are disallowed?

**Edit: Also, what do I need to use instead of $(window.top)?**

Thanks.

Comment: Set Firebug to break on errors.

Comment: @Slaks the errors are shown in chrome/safari - as far as I know, only firebug lite is available in these browsers.

Comment: Set Chrome to break on errors.

Comment: Lol, I will see if there's a way to do that, didn't know..

Comment: The purple/black Pause button on the bottom of the Script tab.

Comment: What are you asking about `$(window.top)`?

Comment: Will $(window.top) result in such an error? I have enabled breaking, but now I just get the a line from inside some jquery object, not from my code, and there doesn't seem to be a way to go backwards in time to see which line of my code caused the issue.

Comment: Look at the call stack.  `$(window.top)` is useless; `window.top` isn't an element.

Comment: The call stack are all anonymous jquery functions I'm afraid.

Comment: Look at the variables at different levels of the callstacks.  What's at the bottom? What is it responding to?

Comment: The only code in the callstack that is not from jquery is one that does $(obj).data('key'); This should certainly still work with iframes..

Comment: Not necessarily.  What's `obj`?

Comment: A div element on the page requested. (not in a sub or parent frame).

Comment: That should not be nearly so complicated.  Look inside the call frames and try to figure out what jQuery is doing, or show me a demo.

Comment: Figured it out, but thanks anyway Slaks!

Comment: Just had to remove all the references to document.top / window.top and some other such things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you own all of the pages (the containing document and the iframe document) just stick some javascript in each of them to allow them to communicate happily:

```
document.domain = 'myDomain.com';
```

Answer (score 0):

Any call from inside the frame to window instead of window.frames[my frame] will cause a violation unless you have the document.domain set to match the parent.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain