# jQuery on MTurk, why does Chrome report "Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain, mechanicalturk

I'm doing a couple of things with jQuery in an MTurk HIT, and I'm guessing one of these is the culprit. I have no need to access the surrounding document from the iframe, so if I am, I'd like to know where that's happening and how to stop it!

Otherwise, MTurk may be doing something incorrect (they use the 5-character token `&amp;` to separate URL arguments in the iframe URL, for example, so they DEFINITELY do incorrect things).

Here are the snippets that might be causing the problem. All of this is from within an iframe that's embedded in the MTurk HIT** (and related) page(s):

1. I'm embedding my JS in a `$(window).load()`. As I understand it, I need to use this instead of `$(document).ready()` because the latter won't wait for my iframe to load. Please correct me if I'm wrong.
2. I'm also running a RegExp.exec on `window.location.href` to extract the workerId.

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate. Indeed - after writing this, SO seems to have a made a good guess at this: [Debugging "unsafe javascript attempt to access frame with URL ... "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069795/debugging-unsafe-javascript-attempt-to-access-frame-with-url). I'll answer this question if I figure it out before you do.

It'd be great to get a good high-level reference on where to learn about this kind of thing. It doesn't fit naturally into any topic that I know - maybe learn about cross-site scripting so I can avoid it?

** If you don't know, an MTurk HIT is the unit of work for folks doing tasks on MTurk. You can see what they look like pretty quick if you navigate to http://mturk.com and view a HIT.

I've traced the code to the following chunk run within jquery from the inject.js file:

`try {
    isHiddenIFrame = !isTopWindow && window.frameElement && window.frameElement.style.display === "none";
} catch(e) {}`

Comment: Doing some more poking around: window.location.href is accessing the src of the iframe. So, that seems like it should be totally legit. Also, http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/ indicates that the iframe owns it's own `window` object. That said, if I disable my javascript, the problem goes away... so I know more, but I'm more confused now :)

Comment: Well - I wouldn't quite call this "solved" yet. But in any case, the issue seems to occur when I am using jQuery (so I "cause" it), but it only happens on the worker / public view of a HIT, not on the requester / developer side. So, there's also something specific that Amazon is doing. It's actually a caught exception. So, I don't see why I'm getting it in the javascript console. See above for where it is in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar issue running jQuery in MechanicalTurk through Chrome.
The solution for me was to download the jQuery JS files I wanted, then upload them to the secure amazon S3 service.
Then, in my HIT, I called the .js files at their new home at https://s3.amazonaws.com.

Tips on how to make code 'secure' by chrome's standards are here:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html

Comment: Rad. I'm just now turning back towards some MTurk hacking, so your solution is surprisingly well-timed considering the age of my question!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but our lab has been successful at circumventing (read hack) this problem by asking workers click on a button inside the iframe that opens a separate pop-up window. Within the pop-up window, you're free to use jQuery and any other standard JS resources you want without triggering any of AMT's security alarms. This method has the added benefit of allowing workers to view your task in a full-sized browser window instead of AMT's tiny embedded iframes.

Comment: My "solution" was to ignore it, because it doesn't cause any problems. It just keeps me worried because I don't understand why I'm getting the problem at all. A point for sharing, though!